# How to read a PDF file from my PC through PDF application in my android emulator

Tags: android, pdf, android-emulator

I have a PDF reader application in my Android Emulator. I want to read a PDF file stored in my PC hard disk through the Emulator. how can i load my PDF files into Emulator?

plz help me.....

Answer (score 0):

open eclipse>ddms save your pdf file in your emulator's sdcard
then run application which reads PDF files such as
adobe reader or u can create ur own application

u can download PDFbox API to read PDF in android try this link: "http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html#pdfbox"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse you can move files to and from the SD Card through the Android Perspective (it is called DDMS in Eclipse). Just select the Emulator in the left part of the screen and then choose the File Explorer tab. Above the list with your files should be two symbols, one with an arrow pointing at a phone, clicking this will allow you to choose a file to move to phone memory.

or

[see this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_pull-push_files_from-to_the_emulator_eclipse-t113.html)